# Mouse pointer renderer

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi

I'm thinking about creating a software with c++ targeting Windows 7 (using Windows api) that allows a second mouse pointer on the same PC, so my question is witch part of Windows is handling the rendering of the mouse pointer?
I believe that understanding how it actually works will allow me to imitate it in order to render a second mouse pointer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows's windowing system only supports a single "true" cursor: it is a low-level feature of the 2D graphics chipset (which is why the cursor doesn't appear in screenshots). Windows sets aside a separate area of video memory that holds the bitmap of the cursor: either a DDB (device-dependent bitmap) with an AND/XOR channel (for indexed opacity and color inversion), or a 32bpp RGBA surface for alpha-transparent cursors (which is how the "show cursor shadow" feature is implemented). My understanding is that the cursor is applied to the actual output image as it is "scanned" by the output device (e.g. the DAC for VGA-out or whatever DVI and HDMI use), so it never exists in the framebuffer - this is how the cursor worked in the days before we had composited window managers and without having to ask applications to redraw themselves where the cursor had been.

Using this special trick for the cursor is also necessary to keep latency to a minimum. If you write a program that draws to a windows surface (e.g. with GDI or even through OpenGL or Direct3D) you'll see it lags behind the real cursor by a few miliseconds and this is noticable to users very easily (which is why modern RTS games use this hardware cursor feature instead of reimplementing it themselves).

There is no way to extend this feature that I'm aware of - you will have to be a god of disassembly to modify Windows and graphics drivers to implement the ability to draw multiple cursors.

That's the presentation side of things. Actual application-level support for multiple cursors is also tricky - remember that cursor movement corresponds to various Mouse-related window Messages being sent to hWnds. The problem with two cursors is that these messages will conflict, though theoretically it should work provided they're serialized into a single queue properly. There will be problems with applications, many will make the assumption that, for example, only a single control can be in the Hover state at once, if you have multiple cursors then the application would only respect the most recent cursor message.

I might suggest looking at Windows' multi-touch support, introduced in Windows 7, where it does support multiple simultaneous "cursors", though it is intended for fingers, not mice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion. I didn't think it's that complicated.

Comment: By the way screen recording softwares are actually able to record the mouse cursor, so are they just putting a fake cursor shape on the video?

Comment: @Dai: Applications can support multiple mice without worrying about collisions by using the [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API. This is because you have to register specific devices you are interested in, and then notification messages tell you which device is sending the notification. MSDN even mentions this possibility: "An application can distinguish the source of the input even if it is from the same type of device. **For example, two mouse devices.**"

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, but that's on a per-application basis. The OP wanted to know if he could get Windows to support it by itself and in a way that enables existing applications to work with it.

Comment: I just want to add that the game "The Settlers II" (I think the first one as well) had support for multiple mice on a splitscreen multiplayer. So it's technically possible, but this was a game in DOS-times and therefore the input propbably didn't use anything like windows messaging.

Comment: @Dai Exactly, I wanted to know the part of windows that draws the mouse, in order to investigate how exactly it is done. I was thinking that I might be able to imitate it to draw another mouse pointer rather than using GDI.